# What's the surface integral of this region?

Tags: calculus

The region $R$ is bounded by cylinder $x^2+y^2=1$ and $z=0$, $x+y+z=2$. Define $n$ to be the normal vector, what's the surface integral of this region: $\iint_R (x,y,z)\cdot n \, \mathrm ds$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will assume $R$ is the surface whose side is the cylinder $x^2+y^2=1$, whose bottom is the disc $x^2+y^2 \le 1$, and whose top is the plane $x+y+z=2$. (I think this is what you meant . . . ?)

Let $\mathbf{F}(x,y,z) = \langle x,y,z \rangle$. By the divergence theorem, 
$$
 \iint_R \mathbf{F} \cdot dS = \iiint_E \text{div } \mathbf{F} \; dV = 3 \iiint_E 1 \; dV
$$
where $E$ is the solid bounded by $R$. Can you take it from here? (Hint: Cylindrical coordinates)